# Substract substring between the last two backslashes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, sql-server-2019

I was wondering how I could find the substring between the last two backslahes in SQL (Microsoft SQL Server 2019).

The values look something like this;

\\000.00.000\abcde\12345\12345-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.doc

I would like to create a new column with the numbers '12345'. The number between the last '\' are the same as the numbers between the last '\' and the first '-'. So, it could be extracted in two possible ways, buy I know neither of them.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please tag the question with it.

Comment: @vakio Microsoft SQL management studio

Comment: SSMS isn't an RDBMS, it's an IDE, like Azure Data Studio or Visual Studio.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Can you ***guarantee*** that the rest of the URL path doesn't have a `-` in it?  *(That `-` **only** appears in the final final name?)*

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

XML and XQuery data model is based on *ordered sequences*.

That's why it is so easy to retrieve any token in a sequence. In our case `[last() - 1]`

No need in a CTE, or any string parsing functions: `SUBSTRING()`, `CHARINDEX()`, `LEN()`, `REVERSE()`, `RIGHT()`, `LEFT()`, etc.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('\\000.00.000\abcde\12345\12345-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.doc'),
('\\000.00.000\abcde\770718\770718-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.txt');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '\';

SELECT ID, tokens
    , result = c.value('(/root/r[last() - 1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') 
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID |                        tokens                         | result |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | \\000.00.000\abcde\12345\12345-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.doc   |  12345 |
|  2 | \\000.00.000\abcde\770718\770718-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.txt | 770718 |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: @ARLeguerb, Please don't miss the explanations in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain SQL without any XML or serialization you could try something like this

```
with yourtable_cte(string) as (
    select * from (values ('\\000.00.000\abcde\12345\12345-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.doc')) v(string))
select yt.*, calc.*,
       substring(yt.string, 
                 calc.len_string-calc.first_slash_loc+2,
                 calc.last_dash_loc-calc.first_slash_loc+1) answer
from yourtable_cte yt
     cross apply (values (len(string),
                          charindex('\', reverse(string)),
                          charindex('-', string))
                          ) calc(len_string, first_slash_loc, last_dash_loc);
```

```
string                                              len_string  first_slash_loc last_dash_loc   answer
\\000.00.000\abcde\12345\12345-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.doc 51          27              31              12345
```

[EDIT] Using the sample data provided by another member

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('\\000.00.000\abcde\12345\12345-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.doc'),
('\\000.00.000\abcde\770718\770718-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.txt');

select yt.*,
       substring(yt.tokens, 
                 calc.len_string-calc.first_slash_loc+2,
                 calc.last_dash_loc-calc.first_slash_loc+1) answer
from @tbl yt
     cross apply (values (len(tokens),
                          charindex('\', reverse(tokens)),
                          charindex('-', tokens))
                          ) calc(len_string, first_slash_loc, last_dash_loc);
```

```
ID  tokens                                                  answer
1   \\000.00.000\abcde\12345\12345-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.doc     12345
2   \\000.00.000\abcde\770718\770718-xxxx-xx-xx-hello.txt   770718
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
DECLARE @value as nvarchar(200) = '\\000.00.000\abcde\12345\12345-xxxx- xx-xx-hello.doc'

SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(@value, LEN(@value) - 
CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@value))),CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(LEFT(@value, 
LEN(@value) - CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@value)))))-1)
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: @ARLeguerb please upvote if worked. this will help the others.